# Can't Perform a React State Update on an Unmounted Component. This is a no-op - Mob X Related

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mobx-react

I'm currently working on a smart home sort of app and are a beginner, and I'm using `mobX` to set the active room names.

I set them in the "Dashboard" Component to the title of the container. Then I want to use the variable stored inside to filter through the rooms in another component called "room". If I hard-code the room name it works, but it throws a bunch of errors when I replace the room name with the actual variable.

I've already tried declaring things within `componentWillUnmount()` but it hasn't worked so far.

This is where I set the variable

```
handleClick(e){
      
        this.props.roomStore.room = e.target.closest('.btn__toggle').querySelector('.btn__headline').innerHTML;
      }
```

This is where I want to get the room

```
loadRooms(){
  if(this.state.isLoaded){
    var locations = this.state.things.filter( function (e){
      return e.location == this.props.roomStore.room}); //<- this is the relevant variable
          const habitems = locations.map((i, key) => 
          <div className="btn__toggle" key={i.UID} type="submit">
          <div className="btn__headline">{i.label}</div>
          </div>
              )
              return habitems;
            }         
}
```

And this is where I render my Items:

```
render() {
   
        if(this.state.isLoaded){
          return (
            <div>
          <h1 id="h1">{this.props.roomStore.room}</h1>
          <div className="btn__wrapper">{this.loadRooms()}</div>
          </div>
          );
        }
```

I assume it might not work, because the variable gets set in the other component before you actually open the right one, that uses it in render, so the whole component gets rendered before even mounted.

But I might be wrong on that. Any help would be much appreciated.
Errors that occur are:

> index.module.js:860 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
>
> The above error occurred in the  component
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
>
> react-dom.development.js:506 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that your filter function has no access to `this`, leading to the error `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`. You can filter out your `roomStore` from your props using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) beforehand and use it instead of accessing `this.props`.

```
loadRooms() {
    const { roomStore } = this.props;
    if (this.state.isLoaded) {
        var locations = this.state.things.filter( function (e){
            return e.location == roomStore.room
        });

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

> The **destructuring assignment** syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.